# Django-planet shows empty page, while the admin show data that supposed to be displayed

Tags: django

I'm playing with [django-planet](https://github.com/matagus/django-planet) with Django 1.6, and after some (minor) adaptions. I uploaded some feeds (and I can see them in Django-admin) and mounted them in url.py like this:

```
url(r'^feeds/', include('planet.urls'))
```

but when I navigate to `feeds/` or any other url specified in django-planet urls.py :
some examples:

```
url(r'^blogs/$', "blogs_list", name="planet_blog_list"),
url(r'^feeds/$', "feeds_list", name="planet_feed_list"),
```

I get a blank and empty page. **not** an error page. but a blank page. when I look at the request I see the django server returning a 200 status. where are django-planet default pages? When I look at django-planet code the views seem to exists..and else I would get an error page

urls.py doesn't look broken to me, since when I navigate to non existent urls in `feeds/` or otherwise I do get the expected error page.
I have 2 suspicions:

1. django-planet not finding the templates. when I look at the lib structure it seems that views.py is naming views that sit in planet subfolder, but actually planet subfolder is under templates folder.
2. some missing django-planet and undocumented config in my settings.py

how can I solve this?

What am I missing? I'll be glad for help with this

I even downgraded to Django 1.5 but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: first of all, share some of your views code, that would help. as for your suspicions - 1. no, else you'd get an TemplateDoesntExist error 2. try a fresh install inside a virtualenv and see if it helps.

Comment: Have you looked at the templates themselves to make sure they're not being shorted? Do they rely on a base template that you have provided, but which is blank?